# Error when trying to create a new angular project using ng new myProject

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

this is the error issue i've got after type the commande npm new project0

```
npm ERR! path D:\Polytech\Génie Informatique\2- Génie Informatique 4\Programmation Web\Angular\project0\node_modules\js-yaml\bin\js-yaml.jsnpm
ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod                

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'D:\Polytech\Génie Informatique\2- Génie Informatique 4\Programmation Web\Angular\project0\node_modules\js-yaml\bin\js-yaml.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\awouf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-22T08_25_38_203Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and trying again ?

Comment: the node_modules folder was automaticaly created by the command : ```ng new project0```

Comment: I know, but have you tried removing it and reruning your command ?

Comment: yes.. and i only have Error like ```ERROR! project1/angular.json already exists.```

Comment: and if i try the ```ng new ``` command with an other name i have the first Error

Comment: Are you using cywing  or any other linux shell emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try following

```
    npm install angular/cli      //This command will install your angular/cli locally
    ng new project0              //This will create new angular/cli project
    cd project0                  //You will have to CD into project directory
    ng serve --open              // Run your application and open browser
```

You can look into Angular cli documentation for more info https://cli.angular.io/